# How to schedule a second biometrics appointment for a UK visit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm applying for a UK visitor visa from New York. I have completed an application online, have paid the fee, and have already gone to my biometrics appointment.

However, I stupidly just realized that I will need my passport 8 days from now for a different international trip. By the time I return, it will have been approximately 25 days since my biometrics appointment.

Based on what I've seen online, I think my options are:

1. Proceed to submit my passport and visa application to the UK consulate and hope they process it quickly and send me back my passport before my upcoming trip in 8 days.
2. Wait until I return from my trip and at that point submit the application with a 25 day old biometric confirmation attached, and hope the consulate will accept it.
3. Wait until I return from my trip and then start a whole new application, pay the fee again, get my biometrics taken again, and then submit.

Any other options? Is there any way to schedule a second biometrics appointment after already having gone to the first one, so I don't have to start a whole new application?

Comment: Option 2) could be viable.  Contact the consulate or the office where biometrics is scheduled to confirm (2) would work.  1) is way too risky IMHO.

Comment: You could try option 1 along with paying extra for one of the 'premium' processing options. That's supposed to give you a speedy decision & turnaround.

Comment: It seems that option 2 wouldn't be possible as 25 days is too long. According to [Apply for a UK visa in the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa): `Your biometric confirmation receipt will be stamped at your appointment. You then have 5 days to post this, your application form, your passport and supporting documents to UK Visas and Immigration (UKVI).`

Answer (score 1):

*1. Proceed to submit my passport and visa application to the UK consulate and hope they process it quickly and send me back my passport before my upcoming trip in 8 days time.*

It might happen (although you might not want to rely on it): UK [visit visa processing times](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/united-states/all) for those applying from within the US:

> General Visit (6 months or less):
>   Most applications are processed within 15 days.
>
> **Number of days to process application* ::: % of applications decided**
>   3 days  :::  2% 
>   5 days  :::  9%
>   10 days ::: 75%
>   15 days ::: 97%
>   30 days ::: 99%
>   60 days ::: 100%

*2. Wait until I return from my trip and at that point submit the application with a 25 day old biometric confirmation attached, and hope the consulate will accept it.*

As @MrAndySweet commented, that may present problems:

> [Apply for a UK visa in the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa):
>
> Your biometric confirmation receipt will be stamped at your appointment. You then have 5 days to post this, your application form, your passport and supporting documents to UK Visas and Immigration (UKVI).

*3. Wait until I return from my trip and then start a whole new application, pay the fee again, get my biometrics taken again, and then submit.*

That would be up to you, your finances, and plans for visiting the UK.

*Any other options? Is there any way to schedule a second biometrics appointment after already having gone to the first one, so I don't have to start a whole new application?*

[Priority visa service](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/applicationcentre.html#7)

> This is an optional service where you can pay an extra fee to fast track your application and have your visa application processed ahead of non priority applications.
>
> You must pay for the priority visa service online on the VFS Global website before you post your application. The VFS [User pay services](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/user_pay_services.html#5) page contains further information on how to apply, the fee and how to pay for this service.

The [selections](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/usa/applicationcentre.html#land-on-table):

- Gold, $1600, next-business day processing (please take note of cut of times), no prior appointment required.
- Silver, $750, priority processing, usually within 5 working days, prior appointment required but not needed with payment of additional $75 walk in fee (accepted on first-come first-serve basis).
- Bronze, $310, standard processing – usually within 15 working days, prior appointment required but not needed with payment of additional $75 walk in fee (accepted on first-come first-serve basis).